# Channel Impulse Response is zero mean Gaussian random variable?

Tags: gaussian, information-theory, stochastic

In the Paper "Key Generation From Wireless Channels" the channel estimation is given as:
$\tilde{h}_{1,A} = \sigma_1^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{||S_B||^2}$,
$\tilde{h}_{1,A} = \sigma_1^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{||S_A||^2}$

So the different $\tilde{h}_{1,x}$ are zero mean Gaussian random variables with some variance.

At the end, they calculate the secret key rate by

$R_s = \frac{1}{T} I \left( \tilde{h}_{1,A}, \tilde{h}_{1,B}  \right) = \frac{1}{2T} \log\left( {1+\frac{\sigma_1^4 P^2 T^2}{4(\sigma^4+\sigma^2+\sigma_1^2PT)}} \right)$, there P is power and T is the coherence time.

I would like to calculate that for WiFi at 2.4 GHz. I'm searching for a typical value for the variances $\sigma$ and $\sigma_1$. In addition, a value for 60 GHz would be also awesome.

Comment: Those variances can go from 0 (for a static environment) to very large... they depend on the properties of the specific channel you're measuring on.

Comment: @MBaz, thanks for your response. But I'm searching for a typical value for 2.4 GHz and 60 Ghz. I don't core how precise that is. :)